# Hide "Rendering Problems" hint in android studio

Tags: xml, rendering, hide, android-studio

Is there any possibility to hide the annoying popup in the xml editors preview which says there are rendering problems?

It overlaps half of the preview

Comment: Is ti possible to hide it completely in the latest version?

Comment: It is a real problem for me too. I write in Xamarin for Visual Studio but use Android Studio solely for XML layouts (since the Xamarin WYSIWYG editor is slow and rubbish) and have to keep dismissing the same hint over and over again

Answer (score 7):

Rule of thumb: don't fix the symptom, fix the problem!

You only get this when you are using custom views. In this case, in your custom view Java file, you should have a section like the below to give the renderer data to work with.

```
    if(!this.isInEditMode()) {
        this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"appFont.otf"););
    }
```

This will set the typeface to "appFont.otf" when the renderer is trying to render your custom view in the preview window.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not possible if you are using an external view, though

Comment: I think its a fair question. It obscures my view of what I am designing and I am not able to remove the source of the errors because I cannot target a newer SDK. So I have to live with the pointless problems. I'd like to hide them.

Comment: Agree with @user3690202 - I'm using a 3rd party lib that has a rendering issue and every single time I change the xml file it's embedded in, my whole view of the editor is obstructed.  I want to disable this feature.

Answer (score 1):

AS 0.1.8 allows you to dismiss this. Look for a tiny close marker at the top left of the overlay.

Comment: I know, but I don´t want to appear it again, because it pops up on every single change I make in the xml code

Comment: I hate that dialog also

Answer (score 0):

As @TheHungryAndroider correctly points out, you should try and fix the problem causing the annoying pop up, not simply hide the pop-up. However, this is not possible if you are using a class from an external library. In this case, the only sensible work around I've been able to come up with is to subclass the offending class and override the constructor or the `onDraw` method and make use of the `isInEditMode` method to avoid the problem in the preview inspector. The stack trace from the pop-up will be useful here.

The obvious fix is to return early from `onDraw` if your are in edit mode, and this will make the preview simply not draw anything where the element is placed. You could be smarter if you wanted, and draw something like the element that doesn't cause an error. I all depends on how much you need the preview and how you're feeling :P

**Example**

```
public class LessBuggyCircularImageView extends CircularImageView {

    public LessBuggyCircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    }
    // Could be really smart here
}
```

Comment: That is really a great solution when a library is used for some custom views.

Answer (score 0):

As of Android Studio 2.3 this issue has been fixed. 
The stable release of Android Studio 2.3 can be downloaded as of today.

Comment: How do you hide it in 2.3? Where is the option for that?

Comment: Asking where to hide it, no answers.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to Android Studio 2.3 http://tools.android.com/download/studio

then  “Rendering Problems” can be hidden by click a button at right-top